# How to auto delete OTP using Deletion Key Event

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I basically need to confirm user account with OTP , filling with continous flow of numbers works fine but when i try to delete otp numbers in continious flow it does not work , i would appreciate anyone help , Thank you

- This is my edittext from layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter OTP"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionPrevious"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/otpEditLineColor"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionPrevious"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/otpEditLineColor"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionPrevious"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/otpEditLineColor"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionPrevious"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/otpEditLineColor"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionPrevious"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/otpEditLineColor"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/otpEditLineColor"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionPrevious"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            style="@style/RectangleButtonLoginStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/verify"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Verify"
            style="@style/RectangleButtonLoginStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

- This is what i have tried to so far

```
 private fun fillInWithOtp(edit1: EditText, edit2: EditText, edit3: EditText, edit4: EditText, edit5: EditText, edit6: EditText) {
        edit1.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if(s!!.trim().toString().isNotEmpty()){
                    edit2.requestFocus()
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }
        })
        edit2.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if(s!!.trim().toString().isNotEmpty()){
                    edit3.requestFocus()
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }
        })
        edit3.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if(s!!.trim().toString().isNotEmpty()){
                    edit4.requestFocus()
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }
        })
        edit4.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if(s!!.trim().toString().isNotEmpty()){
                    edit5.requestFocus()
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }
        })
        edit5.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                if(s!!.trim().toString().isNotEmpty()){
                    edit6.requestFocus()
                }
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }
        })

        // Set up the key listener for each EditText
        setDeleteKeyListener(edit1, edit2)
        setDeleteKeyListener(edit2, edit3)
        setDeleteKeyListener(edit3, edit4)
        setDeleteKeyListener(edit4, edit5)
        setDeleteKeyListener(edit5, edit6)

    }

    private fun setDeleteKeyListener(currentEdit: EditText, nextEdit: EditText) {
        currentEdit.setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                currentEdit.text.clear() // Clear the content of current EditText
                if (currentEdit.isFocused && currentEdit.text.isEmpty()) {
                    nextEdit.requestFocus() // Move focus to the next EditText
                }
                true // Return true to indicate that the event is handled
            } else {
                false // Return false if the event is not handled
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
private fun setKeyListener(fromEditText: EditText,backToEditText : EditText){

fromEditText.set0nKeyListener { _,_,event ->
  if (null != event && KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL == event.keyCode) {
     backToEditText.isEnabled = true
     backToEditText.requestFocus()
     backToEditText.setText(" ")
     fromEditText.clearFocus()
     }
 false
   }
}
```

And I called it like this :

```
setKeyListener(fromEditText= editTextTwo, backToEditText = editText0ne)
setKeyListener(fromEditText = editTextThree, backToEditText = editTextTwo)
setKeyListener(fromEditText = editTextFour, backToEditText= editTextThree)
```

You were passing the edit texts in setDeleteKeyListner the wrong way as while deleting we're going backwards so the nextEditText would be the previous one.

Comment: It did work but for example if i write otp , then delete all of it , and try again to write the otp , it does not allow to write anything

Comment: @Taki why is that so? you just have to clear text in each of the edit texts, can you include the code related to that